# Sum from the different tables Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have couple of tables which stores amount and I want to group by and get sum - reason for the mutiple tables are nhibernate descriminators. 
I am using Union all and works but query is very big.

I am using following query

```
     SELECT CustomerAccountNumber,
       vc.CustomerName,
       SUM(PermAmount) AS PermAmount,
       SUM(FreetextAmount) AS FreetextAmount,
       (SUM(PermAmount) + SUM(FreetextAmount)) AS TotalAmountByCustomer
FROM
(
    SELECT pp.CustomerAccountNumber,
           pl.Amount AS PermAmount,
           0 AS FreetextAmount
    FROM dbo.PermanentPlacementTransactionLine pl
         INNER JOIN dbo.TransactionLine tl ON pl.TransactionLineId = tl.Id
         INNER JOIN dbo.PermanentPlacement pp ON pl.PermanentPlacementId = pp.Id
    WHERE tl.CurrentStatus = 1
    GROUP BY pp.CustomerAccountNumber,
             pl.Amount,
             tl.Id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ft.CustomerAccountNumber,
           0 AS PermAmount,
           ft.Amount AS FreetextAmount
    FROM dbo.FreeTextTransactionLine fttl
         INNER JOIN dbo.TransactionLine tl ON fttl.TransactionLineId = tl.Id
         INNER JOIN dbo.[FreeText] ft ON fttl.FreeTextId = ft.Id
    WHERE tl.CurrentStatus = 1
    GROUP BY ft.CustomerAccountNumber,
             ft.Amount,
             tl.Id
) WIPSummary
INNER JOIN dbo.vw_Customer vc ON WIPSummary.CustomerAccountNumber = vc.CustomerAccount
GROUP BY CustomerAccountNumber,
         vc.CustomerName;
```

is there any elegant way of displaying amount in separate columns ? 
I can use partition by if it was same table and want to display row by row.

Comment: Can you show a small sample output of this query and your desired output? You could probably use a partition by if you first wrap this in a CTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these query, is easy to understand and probably faster than yours.

I assume that the values are unique in your view

```
WITH cte_a 
     AS (SELECT pp.customeraccountnumber 
                ,Sum(pl.amount) AS PermAmount 
                ,0              AS FreetextAmount 
         FROM   dbo.permanentplacementtransactionline pl 
                INNER JOIN dbo.transactionline tl 
                        ON pl.transactionlineid = tl.id 
                INNER JOIN dbo.permanentplacement pp 
                        ON pl.permanentplacementid = pp.id 
         WHERE  tl.currentstatus = 1 
         GROUP  BY pp.customeraccountnumber), 
     cte_b 
     AS (SELECT ft.customeraccountnumber 
                ,0              AS PermAmount 
                ,Sum(ft.amount) AS FreetextAmount 
         FROM   dbo.freetexttransactionline fttl 
                INNER JOIN dbo.transactionline tl 
                        ON fttl.transactionlineid = tl.id 
                INNER JOIN dbo.[freetext] ft 
                        ON fttl.freetextid = ft.id 
         WHERE  tl.currentstatus = 1 
         GROUP  BY ft.customeraccountnumber) 
SELECT vc.customeraccountnumber 
       ,vc.customername 
       ,Isnull(A.permamount, 0)       AS PermAmount 
       ,Isnull(B.freetextamount, 0)   AS FreetextAmount 
       ,Isnull(A.permamount, 0) 
        + Isnull(B.freetextamount, 0) AS TotalAmountByCustomer 
FROM   dbo.vw_customer vc 
       LEFT JOIN cte_a a 
              ON vc.customeraccount = A.customeraccountnumber 
       LEFT JOIN cte_b b 
              ON vc.customeraccount = A.customeraccountnumber
```

if no table structures and sample data, that is the best I can do to help you.